# How to dynamically generate waypoints using jquery waypoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically, I'm trying to create dynamic waypoints for this menu I am creating. I have several waypoints that need to be created(30+).  Here is what I have so far:

```
//arrays
var contentArray = new Array(
    "#1790", "#1792", "#1794", "#1720", "#1724", "#1726", "#1728", "#1647", "#1649", "#1651", "#1660", "#1662", "#1664", "#1667",
    "#1669", "#1671", "#1678", "#1680", "#1683", "#1686", "#1688", "#1690", "#1692", "#1694", "#1696", "#1698", "#1700", "#1702",           "#1704", "#1706", "#1708", "#1710", "#1712", "#1714", "#1716", "#1680-1", "#1680-2" 
);

var tabArray = new Array(
    "1739", "1740", "1741", "1742", "1743", "1744", "1745", "1736", "1748", "1749", "1750", "1751", "1752", "1753",
    "1754", "1755", "1757", "1758", "1761", "1763", "1764", "1765", "1766", "1767", "1768", "1769", "1770", "1772",
    "1773", "1774", "1775", "1776", "1779", "1780", "1781", "1759", "1760"
);

for(var i=0; i<contentArray.length; i++){
    $(contentArray[i]).waypoint({
        handler: function (direction) {

        if(direction == "down") {
            $("#menu-item-" + tabArray[i]).addClass("red-bg");
        } else {
            $("#menu-item-" + tabArray[i]).removeClass("red-bg");
        }
    },
    offset: 0
    })
}
```

The arrays may look a little funky but each index of each array is supposed to correspond with the other array index.  However, each time I run this, the tabArray always returns undefined since it is out of scope.  Is there any way to get around issue? Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Blex's answer is fine, but it is only of a certain scope.  The issue is revolves around how closures work, and how ephemeral data can be lost.  The best/most useful solution is to create object closures like this fully.  Something like the following:

```
function createObjectClosure(item){
  return {
    handler: function(direction) {         
        $("#menu-item-" + item).toggleClass("red-bg", direction == "down");
     },
      offset:0
   }
}
for(var i=0; i<contentArray.length; i++){
    $(contentArray[i]).waypoint(createObjectClosure(tabArray[i]));
}
```

Or (pretty much the same code... many people like this kind of inline function, but I think it is harder for people to follow):

```
for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
    $(contentArray[i]).waypoint(
        function(item) {
            return {
                handler: function(direction) {
                  $("#menu-item-" + item).toggleClass("red-bg", direction == "down");
                },
                offset: 0
            }
        }(tabArray[i])
    )
}
```

Comment: Good example. Just spotted a typo. You're missing a closing square bracket in the first example when using `tabArray[i`. But +1. **Edit** : can you please replace the `if` statement with `toggleClass`? Then the answer would be perfect.

Comment: @blex Just for you, changed the toggleClass.  : )

Comment: whoa, this solutions works perfectly! Thanks for all the contribution from everyone! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by adding the corresponding "tab" as an attribute to it, like `data-tab`:

```
for(var i=0; i<contentArray.length; i++){
    // Add the data-tab to the element and create waypoint
    $(contentArray[i]).attr('data-tab', tabArray[i]).waypoint({
        handler: function (direction) {
            // Grab the data-tab attribute and use it
            var tab = $(this.element).data('tab');
            // You can toggle it without an if statement
            $("#menu-item-" + tab).toggleClass("red-bg", direction == "down");
        },
        offset: 0
    })
}
```

Comment: Btw (not to start trouble), have you tested this?  I'd be afraid that the `this` scope would be lost when the handler gets invoked.  A quick look through the Waypoint source code suggest that the target would wind up being $(this.element), but I haven't bothered to download a sample to check through it.

Comment: @JohnGreen I haven't tested it, but you might very well be right. Waypoint's `this` probably refers to its instance, and not to the actual DOM element. I edited that, but it should be tested.